# Are Textures cached by GPU or buffered from memory for every frame?

Tags: gpu

Are the textures buffered from memory(RAM) for each Draw Call/Frame or are cached in VRAM.

As per my research, I believe in the former case, if it is, then isn't the second approach a better option?

For example, in First Person Shooter games, the weapon is going to be rendered 98% of the time, so are those weapon textures cached by the GPU locally?

I am not sure about this, so I hope someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1):

They're usually stored in GPU memory. In some cases, when the GPU has to evict them, they will need to be restored from CPU-side memory, but this is "uncommon" unless you are really thrashing the card.

You should never see them populated from CPU every frame under normal conditions unless you are also updating the texture CPU-side every frame.

Comment: I would like to add that changing the texture every frame will be poor for performance.